# Curves in Godot 4

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot-4

I'm trying to figure out how to use curves to ease variable values in Godot 4.

Ok, I've created a curve like this:

```
@export var test_curve: Curve
```

[image]

I set up my curve and... how do I use it?

I've tried this:

```
test_curve.sample_baked(want_to_ease_this_var_w_curve)
```

It does nothing at all. What is the correct way of using a curve like this in Godot 4?

Comment: How do you use the return value of this sampling function in your code?

Comment: I'm trying to use it like this:

`if Input.is_action_pressed("crouch"):
  $Head.position.y = test_curve.sample_baked(0.64 + crouching_depth)`

Comment: And what code varies `crouching_depth` over time?

Comment: I assume that the curve length is time and the points are the values that change over time. I have no idea how long this time is, though - this is really confusing to me. When the curve time is up, it just stays at the maximum value. I've tried looking at [Godot documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_curve.html), but either I don't get how to read it or there's no good answer to this question there.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I forgot to provide what you asked for in the first place. The variable code is this:
`@export var crouching_depth = -1`

Comment: So you are querying it at the same point always, aren't you?

Comment: I don't know what that means, sorry. I'm not a coder.

Comment: Also, I should've added - what I'm trying to achieve is smooth crouch, where the smoothness is determined by a curve. I'd like to use it instead of a lerp.